# search parent with 2 node

Tags: php, mysql, hierarchy

I have example hierarchy:

```
id   name    parent 
1    a       null
2    b       1
3    c       2
4    d       2
5    e       2
6    f       1
7    g       6
8    h       6
9    i       6
```

if I want to search parents between "c" and "g" or between "c" and "e". How do I do that?
I already tried the script from [here](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/)
but I can't find a solution for my problem, anyone can help me? I'm not an expert with algorithms, and please help with php code

I want the output

if "c" and "g" I want to output "a" and if "c" and "e" I want output "b"

Comment: What do you mean with `parent between "c" and "g"`, should it return `"a,b,f"`? Can you add expected output?

Comment: if "c" and "g" i want return to "a" and if "c" and  "e" iwant return to "b"

Answer (score 0):

Use this query to get the parent.

```
SELECT name from hierarchytbl where id IN (SELECT Min(parent) 
   FROM hierarchytbl WHERE parent != null and name BETWEEN 'c' and 'g')
```

Answer (score 0):

mysql> SELECT name from hier where id IN (SELECT Min(parent) FROM hier WHERE name BETWEEN 'c' and 'g');
+------+
| name |
+------+
| a    |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> SELECT name from hier where id IN (SELECT Min(parent) FROM hier WHERE name BETWEEN 'c' and 'e');
+------+
| name |
+------+
| b |
+------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)